# Exception using CheckBoxComboBox from CodeProject

Tags: combobox, checkbox, dllimport

I am using .NET 3.5 and programming in VB. I recently came accross the need to have a multi select dropdown box.  I tried to disuade my manager from I did my usual google searches as .NET does not come with a standard drop down component that allows this functionality.

I found this [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/extending_combobox.aspx)

I downloaded the demo and it works exactly the way I want it to work in my application.  However when I attempt to add this component to my project, it fails at base.WndProc(ref m) and says that the string is an invalid boolean.  Ideally I would debug this and pass in a boolean as it sounds like it's getting a string instead of the expected boolean. But I can't modify the WndProc() method. Or can I?

Or if anyone else has looked at this article and gotten it to successfully work. I'd appreciate any advice on the matter.